# Application.Exit calls FormClose event

Tags: c#, winforms, formclosing

I am working in .NET4.5 Winforms C#.

My application is based on Model View Controller pattern. On the main form (view) I have a button Exit. If the user presses this button, a method is called on the controller that cleans up stuff and then calls Application.Exit(). This works fine.

I also would like to run this method when the user presses the default windows exit-cross in the top-right window. To do this I handle the FormClosing event. In this Event I call again the controller method which calls Application.Exit();

The problem now is that Application.Exit() also fires the FormClosing event. Which creates a double call. Of course I can make a flag and test for this, but I feel I am doing something wrong.

What is the correct way to close my winforms application and cleanup the required things. I don't want to cleanup in the formclosing event of the view, seems ugly.

Comment: Have the Exit button close the form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is to include your cleanup code in a method that is being called in your `FormClosing` event handler (nothing ugly in that, in my opinion). Calling `Application.Exit` or closing the application the old-fashioned way then results in this event being generated. Which triggers the cleanup method.

```
private void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Application.Exit();
}

private void FormClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
  Cleanup();
}

private void Cleanup()
{
  // do cleanup here
}
```

Comment: But this means the cleanup code resides in my View? Of course this works fine, but should cleanup code (databases access, file closing, etc..) not happen in a controller or model? I am trying to make the view as dumb as possible so I can replace it with any other GUI and test better.

Comment: I just would like to send an event to my controller and from there handle the application closing...

Comment: That is what you would do in Cleanup.